# Acceleration of a particle varies with distance as $-kx$. The particle is initially given a velocity $v_0$. Find time take to reach initial point

Tags: kinematics

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$I am having a problem here because acceleration varies with distance, and I am not able to relate it with time

\begin{align}
a &=-\frac{kx}{m} \\
v\frac{\d v}{\d x} &= -\frac{kx}{m}
\end{align}
For $x_{\max}$
\begin{align}
0-v_{0}^2 &= -\frac{kx^2}{m} \\
x &= \sqrt{\frac{mv_0}{k}}
\end{align}

But I still can’t find time

Comment: You have been given an example of simple harmonic motion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion#:~:text=In%20mechanics%20and%20physics%2C%20simple,of%2C%20the%20object's%20displacement%20vector.

Comment: Hint: solve line 2 to get v in terms of x. Then substitute v = dx/dt and solve for x in terms of t.

Comment: Well, this is a math discussion area..... but never mind - questions are **inevitable**.....

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$We have,
$$
v \,\d v =-Cx \,\d x \\
\int_{v_0}^{v(x)} v \,\d v = -C\int_0^x x\,\d x \\
\frac{v(x)^2-v_0^2}{2}=-Cx \\
v(x)=\sqrt{v_0^2-2Cx},
$$
where $C=\frac km$. Using $v=\frac{\d x}{\d t}$, $$\frac{\d x}{\sqrt{v_0^2-2Cx}} = \d t$$ Now just integrate both sides to get an expression for $x(t)$, after which you need to solve $x(t)=0$.